# Cisco interface vlan (shutdown vs no ip address)

Tags: cisco, vlan, cisco-catalyst, cisco-commands

What is the difference in functionality between these two commands.

```
interface Vlan10
  shutdown

interface Vlan10
  no ip address
```

I haven't been able to find any source material, but I've seen other websites describe both commands as disabling the L3 interface for the specified VLAN. Preventing routing off of the subnet.

For example: [shutdown](https://community.cisco.com/t5/switching/shut-down-vlan-and-interface-vlan-shutdown/m-p/1945950) vs [no ip address](https://community.cisco.com/t5/other-network-architecture-subjects/int-vlan-10-no-ip-address/td-p/333728)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IPv4 is not the only layer-3 protocol. We have IPv6, and Cisco has supported others, too.

You could, for example, have something like this:

```
interface Vlan10
 no ip address
 ipv6 address 2001:db8:1234:5678:90ab:cdef:1111:2222/64
!
```

The VLAN interface in this example is still active at layer-3 (IPv6 is a layer-3 protocol, too) even without an IPv4 address. With no layer-3 addressing, it is still an active layer-2 interface, and you can do other things like apply layer-2 ACLs. It is much like a physical interface, except that it applies to the entire VLAN on that switch.

The `shutdown` command actually stops all processing on the interface, regardless of any other configuration on the interface.

Comment: The other advantage of using the 'shutdown' command instead of removing configuration of the addresses is that you don't have to put them back and risk a mistake/typo if you want to enable the interface again. A simple 'no shut' enables the interface again without the chance of a wrong IP address or network mask/length.

Comment: Is there a difference in function between `int vlan10 shutdown` and `no int vlan10`?